# snowflake.connector SQL compilation error invalid identifier from pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-connector

I'm trying to ingest a df I created from a json response into an existing table (the table is currently empty because I can't seem to get this to work)

The df looks something like the below table:

| index | clicks_affiliated |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 3214 |
| 1 | 2221 |

but I'm seeing the following error:

> snowflake.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 000904 (42000): SQL
> compilation error:  error line 1 at position 94
> invalid identifier '"clicks_affiliated"'

and the column names in snowflake match to the columns in my dataframe.

This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
from snowflake.sqlalchemy import URL
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import snowflake.connector
from snowflake.connector.pandas_tools import write_pandas, pd_writer
from pandas import json_normalize
import requests

  
df_norm = json_normalize(json_response, 'reports')

#I've tried also adding the below line (and removing it) but I see the same error
df = df_norm.reset_index(drop=True)

   
def create_db_engine(db_name, schema_name):
    engine = URL(
        account="ab12345.us-west-2",
        user="my_user",
        password="my_pw",
        database="DB",
        schema="PUBLIC",
        warehouse="WH1",
        role="DEV"
    )
    return engine


def create_table(out_df, table_name, idx=False):
    url = create_db_engine(db_name="DB", schema_name="PUBLIC")
    engine = create_engine(url)
    connection = engine.connect()

    try:
        out_df.to_sql(
            table_name, connection, if_exists="append", index=idx, method=pd_writer
        )

    except ConnectionError:
        print("Unable to connect to database!")

    finally:
        connection.close()
        engine.dispose()

    return True

print(df.head)

create_table(df, "reporting")
```

Comment: Do the column names match case, as well.  The object appears to be quoted, which means the case will matter in Snowflake.

Comment: @MikeWalton when I print out df.columns I don't see them in double quotes I see: Index(['clicks_affiliated'], etc.)

Comment: The error message shows the quoted object, which means that's what the python connector is doing for you.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

So... it turns out I needed to change my columns in my dataframe to **uppercase**

I've added this after the dataframe creation to do so and it worked:

```
df.columns = map(lambda x: str(x).upper(), df.columns)
```

Comment: Yep - this is what I was getting at.

Comment: @MikeWalton Thank you for your help w. this!

Comment: I see the solution but I do not understand it. Why would Snowflake require upper case or is the str() that does the trick??

Comment: Thank you - this is still happening when using Snowpark and the write_pandas method: the table name must be uppercase.